# Can't figure out how to get rid of field required message on Django form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model form that has a name field and when I submit the form, I get the 'field required' message even when the name field is filled out.

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import User


class Image(models.Model):
    """This model holds information for user uploaded images"""

    # Status of the image
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        PUBLIC = 'public', 'Public'
        PRIVATE = 'private', 'Private'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=7, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.PUBLIC)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['name'], name='name_idx'),
            models.Index(fields=['user'], name='user_idx')
        ]

        ordering = ['-upload_date']
```

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Image
from utils.forms.widgets import text_input, select_input, image_input


class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Use this form to upload images"""
    class Meta:
        model = Image

        fields = [
            'name',
            'image',
            'status',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'name': text_input,
            'image': image_input,
            'status': select_input,
        }
```

[The Error that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEgh3.png)

That's after trying to submit the form with an image selected and the name filled out.

I have tried using the clean_name method to see if returning the name of the image would fix it but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `request.POST` data if it contains the field `name`. Also, directly try adding the data in the `clean` method once.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in the template I forgot to add `enctype='mulitpart-form-data` to the form. Thanks for the help. It turns out the error was with the `image field` and not the `name field`.